# how to send an object from controller to view (Twig) in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Imagine that we have the controller `AdvertController.php` with the edit action `public function editAction(Request $request)` that sends an object `$user` to the view `edit.html.twig`, `$user` contains many attributes ans methods that return a strings

```
public function editAction(Request $request){
$user = new User();
return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:edit.html.twig', array());
}
```

What I need to add in the code ? So that in the view I can display the values

```
edit.html.twig

{{ user.name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in the array() part you already defined.

```
$x = 'someothervalue';
$this->render('template', [
    'somekey' => 'somevalue',
    'someotherkey' => $x
]);
```

Then in twig:

```
{{ somekey }}, {{ someotherkey }}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I have the right to use this method of the controller class just once throughout the query?

Comment: And if I want to send something else while I process my data in the model

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean with the first question. But you can send whatever you like. The php process is not asynchronous so everything executes in order as you write it so any changes you make before rendering the template will be included. You most likely want to select instead of create a user when editing though.

Comment: I mean, as in J2EE I can use SetAttribute at any time of the query, for example I can send a first object using request.setAttribute ('xx', object), and after other execution (Instructions in the program) I use the method request.setAttribute () c second time to send another object

Comment: Just the once, the function returns a [Response](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) object which is basically a wrapper with HTTP headers, status code and the rendered content as a string. So changing any value after the render wont match up. As the HTML is already generated. But the arg is just an array so you could define a variable for it and at any point add things to it, and use it on the `->render()`

Comment: thank you for all , i find it $request->request->set('xx', $object );

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function editAction(Request $request){
   $user = new User();
   return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:edit.html.twig', 
      [
         'user' => $user,
      ]
   );
}
```

In twig template call function `dump()`, and twig render all `new User()` data's:

```
{{ dump(user) }}
```

You can get them like this:

```
{{ user.name }}
{{ user.soname }}
```